# How do I recursively disable my components in Swing?

Tags: java, swing, recursion, jpanel, jcomponent

How do I recursively disable all of my components in a JPanel?

Comment: I don't know, but here is a correction.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
void setEnabled(Component component, boolean enabled) {
    component.setEnabled(enabled);
    if (component instanceof Container) {
        for (Component child : ((Container) component).getComponents()) {
            setEnabled(child, enabled);
        }
    }
}
```

Be aware that the previous enabled/disabled state of each component will be lost, unless you keep track of it somewhere else.

Comment: This is a good (in a relative sense because we still use instanceof...) function.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer works for components and one level of subcomponents.
For a indefinitely recursive solution, use the below:

```
private void setEnabledRecursive(boolean enabled, Component... components) {
   for (Component component : components) {
      component.setEnabled(enabled);
      if (component instanceof Container) {
          setEnabledRecursive(enabled, component);
      }
   }
}
```